# Rails - How update data in table when user clicks on submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using Rails 3.2 and have this page where I am showing a table with a list of results, passed to the view through a @jobs variable which are results from a SQL query, and I want to add a button to this page so that when the user clicks on it, a controller action is called, which does some DB work, then refreshes the table with the up to date results.

I am completely new to JS and AJAX, and pretty green with Rails so I have no clue how to do this.

I create a button like this:

```
<%= form_tag( "controller/get_job", class: "text-center", id: "get-job-form" ) do %>
<%= submit_tag "Get Job", id:"get-job-submit", class: "button" %>
<% end %>
```

thinking that it would call the get_job action of my controller. But I don't want this action to lead to a new page, I just want to "refresh" that table inside the page the user is already on.

My controller action is something like:

```
def get_job
  job = find_job
  job.employee = me
  job.save
  # Here I want to refresh the table so that this new job shows up in   the table
end
```

Do I need some javascript script to do this or is it doable just by calling the controller action and then maybe calling render again?

I am pretty lost, any help is appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the table on your page using javascript. You can get the new table and it's data from an AJAX request.
This might help you: https://blog.codeship.com/unobtrusive-javascript-via-ajax-rails/

Comment: Unfortunately I came across this before and it hasn't really helped. Right now I'm trying to figure out how to even just do a javascript alert when the form button is clicked and its not working out. Where should this javascript code reside, inside the same view directory that my html is? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To do AJAX must be has 3 steps

1. Client sent a request to server
2. Server process with request from client, and send result to client.
3. Client received response from server. Build new DOM HTML.

This [article](http://duyetblog.com/articles/sample-dropdown-ajax-with-rails) maybe help you to understand how ajax works

Comment: I'm not sending any data with that button submit though, it just acts as a trigger for the get_job controller action

Comment: It means you don't need line ```data: data_value``` 

But on your controller, I see ```job = find_job```, but I don't know how to you find_job ?

Comment: It's just an SQL query that returns a job. This gives the user a new job which should then show up in that jobs table

Comment: It was taken random? Because I don't see any condition to take it. But It's not matter. On ajax ```data: data_value``` just send a value to server, to help you process with it. For ex, you send a job_id: 1, and on server, It'll find  a job with Id=1. 

But in here, you don't need it, just remove that line. Now, on your controller, just send a response to clients

Comment: I tried to use a form_tag specifying { :controller => job_controller, :action => get_job } but then it tries to open a get_job view which doesnt exist, and shouldnt exist as I just want it to stay on the current page and reload the table, do you know how to bypass this? Also, what kind of javascript do I need to update this table? Do you have an example?

Comment: Very simple demo. Src [here](https://github.com/duet-ngyen/sample_ajax). But I think you must understand how ajax works before. Read and understand the [article](http://duyetblog.com/articles/sample-dropdown-ajax-with-rails) above

Comment: Thank you, I will try that and report back